# How to use development environment of bigbluebutton

Tags: ubuntu, bigbluebutton

I'm totally puzzled in editing bigbluebutton in my ubuntu server.
I had found how to change the composition of modules in web application, but I don't know how to find development environment (for editing swf file).

Does anyone know how to use development environment of bigbluebutton?

thanks.

Comment: Additionally, my bbb's version is 0.9 and I've already installed openjdk 6

Answer (score 1):

I'm the Product Manager for BigBlueButton.  You'll find all our documentation here

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/

Specifically, for setting up a development environment, see

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/setup.html

Comment: Hi, sorry for spamming your post here, but since you are active on SO, so I thought I will give it a try here itself. If you are free for a couple of minutes some time, can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275490/bigbluebutton-setup-html5-dev-client-login-to-meeting-with-join-api-call-empty-h   and suggest anything that comes to your mind.